# Problem with my 8-to-3 line priority encoder using verilog gate level description

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, encoder

I am attempting to build a working 8-to-3 line encoder using gate level description in verilog. Although, I have working models, in terms of successful compilation and simulation, the recurring issue seems to be that my circuits just do not seem to implement the encoding and thus the priority as they should do.

For instance, when D2 should be encoded as, 100, 101, 110 and 111, it is only being encoded as 100 and 101 and instead D3 is commencing its encoding at 110 and 111, instead of 1000. Please see waveform below:
[image: waveform of issue faced]

This is starting to be a pain in the backside, because regardless of which implementation I use, the results are always the same.

Please also see an example of one such description below:

```
module prior_otb_enco(Y, D, V);
  output   [2:0] Y;
  input    [7:0] D;
  input    V;

  wire    D7_not, D6_not, D5_not, D4_not, D2_not;
  wire    wa0, wa1, wa2, wa3, wa4;;

  //instanitate gates
  not    g0 (D7_not, D[7]),
         g1 (D6_not, D[6]),
         g2 (D5_not, D[5]),
         g3 (D4_not, D[4]),
         g4 (D2_not, D[2]);
  and    g5 (wa0, D6_not, D4_not, D[3]),
         g6 (wa1, D5_not, D4_not, D[3]),
         g7 (wa2, D5_not, D4_not, D[2]),
         g8 (wa3, D6_not, D[5]),
         g9 (wa4, D6_not, D4_not, D2_not, D[1]);
  or     g11(Y[2], D[7], D[6], D[5], D[4]),
         g12(Y[1], D[7], D[6], wa1, wa2),
         g13(Y[0], D[7], wa0, wa3, wa4),
         g14(V, D[0], D[1], D[2], D[3], D[4], D[5], D[6], D[7]);
endmodule
```

Therefore, any insights that anyone can provide will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You might want to look at the diagram for a 74LS148. It is an 8 to 3 inverting priority encoder. Only the highest priority input set low is encoded and inverted, such that if input 0 is low the output is 0x07. Sometimes the hardware helps understand the logic needed in the software.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky256. I was just in the midst of looking at the logic diagram for HCF4532B. But, I'll certainly get onto the 74LS148 diagram once I'm done with the HCF4532B one. Thanks again :)

Comment: On a sidenote @Sparky256, is that your way of saying that one cannot always rely simply on the Boolean functions for correct implementation? :)

Comment: For one thing you have `V` as an input to your module, but then you also connect it to the output of `g14`.

Comment: What I am pointing out is that the pure logic of hardware helps get past the abstraction of software. Once understood you can spot minor errors in your code that are "illogical" in terms of getting the function you want. The Photon may have already spotted a simple typo. The code has to be as perfect as the hardware version, but code has options hardware does not.

Comment: Try: [verilog 8-3 priority encoder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pq6Em.png).

Comment: Lol!  Thanks @ThePhoton. I knew that there was something simple that I was missing ... and that was why I needed a fresh pair of eyes to look at it. :)

Comment: True @Sparky256. My mistake was in simply working off boolean functions defined from a truth table that had not identified V as either an output or input and my subsequent oversights that V should have been identified as an output port in my declarations. Tbh, I'm not quite sure how I managed to missed it; but I'll put it down to tired minds. :)

Comment: Thanks @jonk. I see the errors of my ways now! But, your assistance is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: @aLoHa No problem. Best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to summarize for you what I wrote in comments since it may help others, as well.

---

Here is the verilog I'd consider:

```
module prior_otb_enco( Y, D, V );
  output [2:0] Y;
  input [7:0] D;
  output V;
  wire s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7;
  wire Y2_temp;
  assign s0 = ~ D[7];
  assign s1 = ~ D[6];
  assign s3 = (D[6] | D[5] | D[4]);
  assign s2 = ~ (s1 & D[5]);
  assign s4 = (s3 | D[2] | ~ D[1]);
  assign s5 = ~ s3;
  assign Y2_temp = ~ (s0 & s1 & s2 & ~ D[4]);
  assign s6 = ~ (s5 & D[2]);
  assign s7 = ~ (s5 & D[3]);
  assign Y[1] = ~ (s0 & s1 & s6 & s7);
  assign Y[0] = ~ (s0 & s2 & s4 & s7);
  assign V = ~ (s6 & s4 & s7 & ~ (Y2_temp | D[0]));
  assign Y[2] = Y2_temp;
endmodule
```

---

The equivalent schematic is:

[image]

---

Here are three different behavioral models, all in verilog, that would achieve about the same thing after synthesis:

*example 1*

```
module prior_otb_enco_1( Y, D, V );
  output [2:0] Y;
  input [7:0] D;
  output V;
  reg V;
  reg [2:0] Y;
  always @(D)
    V = 1;
    if ( D[7] )        Y = 7;
    else if ( D[6] )   Y = 6;
    else if ( D[5] )   Y = 5;
    else if ( D[4] )   Y = 4;
    else if ( D[3] )   Y = 3;
    else if ( D[2] )   Y = 2;
    else if ( D[1] )   Y = 1;
    else if ( D[0] )   Y = 0;
    else
      begin
        V = 0;
        Y = 3'b X;
      end
  end
endmodule
```

*example 2*

```
module prior_otb_enco_2( Y, D, V );
  output [2:0] Y;
  input [7:0] D;
  output V;
  reg V;
  reg [2:0] Y;
  always @(D)
    begin
      V = 1;
      casex( D )
        8'b 1XXXXXXX:  Y = 7;
        8'b 01XXXXXX:  Y = 6;
        8'b 001XXXXX:  Y = 5;
        8'b 0001XXXX:  Y = 4;
        8'b 00001XXX:  Y = 3;
        8'b 000001XX:  Y = 2;
        8'b 0000001X:  Y = 1;
        8'b 00000001:  Y = 0;
        default:
          begin
            V = 0;
            Y = 3'b X;
          end
      endcase
    end
endmodule
```

*example 3*

```
module prior_otb_enco_2( Y, D, V );
  output [2:0] Y;
  input [7:0] D;
  output V;
  reg V;
  reg [2:0] Y;
  integer N;
  always @(D)
    begin
      V = 0;
      Y = 3'b X;
      for( N = 0; N < 8; N = N + 1 )
        if ( D[N] )
          begin
            V = 1;
            Y = N;
          end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm still learning my way around this site and was wondering how one obtains a score for a question posed? This question has been viewed over 2000 times, but has yet to obtain a singe score.

Comment: @aLoHa I've never been asked that question before. I suppose you could ask, like you just did. I don't mind adding a +1. But, as best I understand it, one writes a question that is notable for its clarity in setting a context, shows substantial due diligence proving that everything that could be reasonably done has been done already, and asks just a single, well-focused question that is interesting and/or useful and can be directly answered without writing a book. Not a lot of questions here meet that test.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, the insight and also the score for the question. I can imagine that it is not easy to come up with unique questions that meets all those criteria on here; but I'd like to think that the questions which I pose have a level of authenticity to them :)

Comment: @aLoHa I usually work hard to communicate well when I'm answering. I expect to see similar efforts by questioners. It's not fair or respectful of the time of others to write questions which don't illustrate a similar effort to communicate as well as possible, I think. It's okay to not know things. I don't mind that. But I do mind if the questioner can't be bothered to put in substantial effort in framing the situation, communicating as well as possible, and allowing a direct answer rather than *writing a book on some broad topic.*

Comment: @aLoHa  Authenticity matters, of course. But that goes without saying. No one appreciates disingenuousness. So of course that is important, too. But it doesn't by itself make for a good question. It's just that the lack of it would make for a bad question, I think.

Comment: I would like to think that I put a substantial effort into making the questions that I pose as clear as possible for those who may be able to help. After all, it is in my best interest to ensure that others understand my dilemma, if they are to assist me efficiently. So, I totally appreciate where you are coming from.

Comment: @aLoHa Yes. I think that showed. It's most of why I had no problem adding the +1 once you brought my attention back here. In my own defense, we are often focused more upon providing a useful answer (hopefully) and it's often easy to forget to toss the +1 when we should. So I think your reminders will help us do a better job on that score. Don't be shy about it. If you feel you deserve it, just ask. And if your questions continue like this one, I don't think anyone will be annoyed at all. I think they will just realize you are right and give the +1. We should do better at it. Reminders help.

Comment: Thanks and it is much appreciated. Although, I have been a member for a number of years, I am hardly on here, because life often gets in the way, so I am still learning my way around the site. I actually asked the question because I was honestly curious about how one goes about obtaining a score for one's questions. But, it's nice though, when one's question is awarded a score, if deserved. However, I can appreciate that providing a useful answer should be more important than scoring people's questions. Nonetheless, I shall be holding you to your last statement :)

Comment: Why does your 8 to 3 line decoder have 4 outputs?

Comment: @ShashankVM Read the comments to the question itself. It's there.

Comment: @jonk, I read the comments, so the 4th output is to indicate whether the output is a valid decoded value or not?

Comment: @ShashankVM The gate schematic doesn't make it very clear, but the code does. It's a '1' if any of the inputs are '1'. If all the inputs are '0' then it is also '0'. It's really just the output of an 8 input OR gate. How it gets mapped to an optimized schematic depends on the target of synthesis and the quality of the synthesis algorithm in targeting.